# i am getting an integer division or modulo by zero error on the code

Tags: python, for-loop

```
a= int(input())
x=0
i=1
b=round(a/2)
for i in range(b+1):
    mod=a%i
    if mod != 0:
        x=x+1
    else:
        x=x+0
    i=i+1
if x>1:
    print("the number is prime number")
else:
    print("the number is not prime number")
```

this is the code for whether to determine a number is prime number or not
in the line mod = a%i i am getting the error, can you tell me how to solve it

in the input i gave the value of 1 to i, but why i am getting this error i want to know. if there are any other errors you can tell me

Comment: `range(b+1)` *starts with zero*.

Comment: Here's how you track this down.  First, the error indicates that you're dividing (`/` or `//`) or taking a mod value (`%`) by zero.  Your divide clearly isn't the problem, so it must be `mod=a%i`.  So can `i` be zero?  Of course it can.  On the very first iteration of your loop, `i` is zero.  It really is that simple.  Learn to analyze your code.  There are also several other logic errors in your code.  Analyze them and correct them too.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation for the `range` type [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range):

`class range(stop)`

`class range(start, stop[, step])`

> The arguments to the range constructor must be integers (either built-in int or any object that implements the **index**() special method). If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. If step is zero, ValueError is raised.

You have only specified `stop`, so the `start` argument defaults to 0, i.e.

```
 range(7) = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

To start from 1, you should write:

```
 range(1, 7)
```

This will get around the division by zero error, although I think for your program you actually need:

```
 range(2, 7)
```